# Problem with axiomatic approach to defining conditional probability

Tags: probability

I have read several books offering an axiomatic approach to defining conditional probability. In each of these a 'desirable property' is that the ratio of the likelihood of two events given a third, should not change.
I consider two events associated with a throw of a dye. Event, E is an outcome of 1 or 6. Event F is outcome of 1 or 3. Event I is outcomes 1, 2 or 6.
Now P(E) = 1/3, P(F) = 1/3 -  their ratio is 1.
However, P(E|I) = 2/3 and P(F|I) = 1/3. The ratio is now 2:1.
Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: P (E | I) is 2/3; P(F|I) is 1/3, so there's a small typo in your claim. But the question is still a good one!

Answer (score 1):

The desirable proberty is *not*: $$P(E|I):P(F|I)=P(E):P(F)\tag1$$ but it is:$$P(E|I):P(F|I)=P(E\cap I):P(F\cap I)\tag2$$

---

**edit**:

If it comes to events that are subsets of the conditioning event (so $E\subseteq I$ and $F\subseteq I$, wich is not the case in your example) then (1) and (2) are equivalent.

Comment: I'm happy with your desirable property, but the first one is what I am actually seeing in two books.

Comment: @BrianWilliams the first one makes little sense without some extra assumptions. Consider the situation where $F=I$ and $E=I^c$. You must incorporate the $I$ into the right side in some way since both $E$ and $F$ might be dependent on it in completly different ways.

Comment: It could be that they are referring to events $E,F$ that satisfy $E\subseteq I$ and $F\subseteq I$. Then $P(E)=P(E\cap I)$ and $P(F)=P(F\cap I)$.

Comment: DRF: You have helped me solve the problem. There IS another condition, which you've drawn my attention to - both E and F must be contained in I.  Problem solved. Thank you!